# How to delete 1000 rows at a time with SQL Server OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I need to delete rows in a link server's table, 1000 rows at a time.

My code is the following:

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENQUERY (SqlServerAcc, 'SELECT * FROM titles ') > 1000)
BEGIN
    DELETE OPENQUERY (SqlServerAcc,
       'SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber FROM tbl) t WHERE RowNumber <= 1000');
END
```

But I do have errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '>'.
```

at the expression `> 1000`.

I don't understand why this does not work.

Bonus: how can we make the name of the server not hard-coded; in PRD, it should be SqlServerPrd, but it seems that OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments...

Comment: `...'SELECT * FROM titles ') > 1000)` should be `...'SELECT * FROM titles ')) > 1000`. This is just a typographical error.

Comment: Seems odd as well, however, that you check the row count of the table `titles` and then `DELETE` from the table `tbl`. Also `SELECT C FROM OPENQUERY (SqlServerAcc, 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM titles ')` would be more performant as then only a single value needs to be transferred from the remote server, not the *entire* table's content (which then is all basically discarded).